# python regex: inverse match at the end of the line

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am using regex to match patterns in my log. I need to match pattern at the beginning, but then invert the match, ie:

I need to match this line:

```
reject: RCPT from unknown[165.231.143.153]: 450 4.7.25 from=<spameri@tiscali.it> to=<spameri@tiscali.it>
```

But not this line:

```
reject: RCPT from unknown[165.231.143.153]: 450 4.7.25 from=<spameri@tiscali.it> to=<alice@mydomain.com>
```

Basically, if the line contains `to=<alice@mydomain.com>` (or any other email address with `mydomain.com`, then it should not trigger a match. Otherwise if it is anything else, ie `to=<bob@otherdomain.com>`, or `to=<alice@thirddomain.com>`then it should match.

I tried using this  negative look ahead pattern:

```
'^reject: RCPT from [A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\[{ip}\]: .* to=<[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+@(?!mydomain.com)>',
```

where I am negating `mydomain.com` using the construct the construct `(?!mydomain.com)`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookaheads are non-consuming, i.e. the regex index remains where it was and the patterns matched are not added to the overal match value.

Thus, `(?!mydomain.com)` in `(?!mydomain.com)>` checks if there is no `mydomain`, any char, `com` immediately to the right of the current location, and as the next char must be `>`, it is always true.

You need to consume the char before `>` and thus you can use

```
^reject: RCPT from [A-Za-z0-9.-]+\[{ip}]: .* to=<[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@(?!mydomain\.com>)[^>]*>
```

Note you do not need to escape `.` inside square brackets (aka character class) and you do not need to escape `]` when it is not inside a character class.

The `@(?!mydomain\.com>)[^>]*>` matches

- `@`  - a `@` char
- `(?!mydomain\.com>)` - not immediately followed with `mydomain.com>`
- `[^>]*` - (a negated character class matching) any zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.